# Why can I still import an online JS library while I disconnected from WiFi?

Tags: wireless

This is pretty weird.
I have this line in my JavaScript source code file, which obviously used to import a JavaScript library called `d3` from the Internet:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

That file is linked to my HTML file. If I comment that line out, the page cannot load.

Here's the strange thing.
I disconnected my laptop, running Ubuntu, from my WiFi connection. I'm sure that I disconnected and that the WiFi icon was blank. But when I load my HTML file by dropping it to the browser, with the above JavaScript line uncommented, **the page still loaded fine**. That is to said, it had successfully loaded the JS script from `https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`.

I'm not saying that I am not thankful. But what, exactly, happened?

I tried doing the same thing on Windows: Disconnect the Internet and load the file. But the opposite happened: The page couldn't load.

Comment: Check your browser cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because browsers cache these kind of files (js, css) to speed up loading pages and the cache is still available while you are offline.

You can clear your browser cache or add something like `?v1` at the end of your script line to force loading it again like:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js?v1"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your browser cache it's usually set to store files used on web pages to make loading faster.